# Removing Tabbar from tabbedpage leaves blank space. How to remove it?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uitabbar

I want to remove `Tabbar` from `TabbedPage`. I got it working but it leaves blank space or page height is not updated after hiding `Tabbar`.

Note that when we swipe through the pages, the blank goes and never comes back. This issue appears only for the first time.

I have tried from [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/327664/#Comment_327664) link. But it doesn't work.

Also tried following

```
private void Element_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                TabBar.Hidden = true;

                //TabBar.Bounds = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(View.Subviews[0].Frame.X, View.Subviews[0].Frame.Y,
                //                                                     View.Subviews[0].Frame.Width, 0);

                if (TabBar.Hidden)
                {
                    // page
                    View.Subviews[0].Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, View.Subviews[1].Frame.Width, NativeView.Frame.Height);

                    // Tabbar
                    View.Subviews[1].Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(View.Subviews[0].Frame.X, View.Subviews[0].Frame.Y,
                                                                     View.Subviews[0].Frame.Width, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    View.Subviews[1].Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(View.Subviews[1].Frame.X, View.Subviews[1].Frame.Y,
                                                                     View.Subviews[1].Frame.Width, 49);
                    View.Subviews[0].Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(View.Subviews[0].Frame.X, View.Subviews[0].Frame.Y,
                                                                     View.Subviews[0].Frame.Width, View.Subviews[0].Frame.Height - 49);
                }

                //if (TabBar.Hidden)
                //    View.Subviews[1].Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(View.Subviews[1].Frame.X, View.Subviews[1].Frame.Y, View.Subviews[1].Frame.Width, 0);
                //else
                //    View.Subviews[1].Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(View.Subviews[1].Frame.X, View.Subviews[1].Frame.Y, View.Subviews[1].Frame.Width, 49);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //TraceLog("Element_PropertyChanged" + ex.Message);
            }
}
```

**EDIT**

I open tabbed page on list view item clicked. I allow to add multiple tabs dynamically. Also I have created custom tabbar using ContentView that I update when pages are added or removed from TabbedPage.

The sequence is :
- User opens first tab. 
- Click on home icon given on tabbed page. 
- open the second page by click on another list item
- swipe through the page and the page height will be normal.

Here is the code on ListView_ItemTapped (Not posted exactly how is it actually but you can get idea :) )

```
MultiTab ObjMultiTab = new MultiTab(); // Initialize tabbed page

// Get data from server 
ObjMultiTab.Data = ObjData; 
int Id = Convert.ToInt32(ObjData.id); 

if (ActiveList.ContainsKey(Id)) // Dictionary that contains info about index and pageid that are already open 
{ 
   TabId = ActiveList[ObjData.id]; 
   CurrentPage = Children[TabId]; // If user taps on already opend page 
} 
else 
{ 
   Count += 1; ActiveList.Add(Id, Count); 
   Children.Add(new SecondTabbedPage(TableData)); // Or add new child 
   CurrentPage = Children[Count]; 
} 

await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(ObjMultiTab);
```

Is there any way to remove blank space for the first time also ?

Comment: Can you add codes in your xamarin.forms project about the TabbedPage? I did not see the  blank space on my side.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT please see the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding following function to the renderer removed blank space from `TabbedPage`.

```
public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();

    TabBar.Hidden = true;

    var page = View.Subviews[0];
    var tabbar = View.Subviews[1];

    tabbar.Bounds = CGRect.Empty;
    page.Bounds = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution that doesn't require any renders and works on both Android and iOS.

Wrap the `TabbedPage` in a `NavigationPage` so the structure of your app becomes

- NavigationPage (root)

  - TappedPage

    - NavigationPage

      - ContentPage (with tabbar)
  - ContentPage (without tabbar)

On the TabbedPage you have to hide the navigationbar of the 'root' NavigationPage, otherwise you have 2 navbars.

```
<TabbedPage
    ...
    HasNavigationBar="False">
```

If you push a page using the 'root' `NavigationPage`, the tabbar is hidden and there is no blank space at the bottom.

--- **Edit** ---

See my example at:
https://github.com/Jfcobuss/HideTabbarExample/tree/master/HideTabbarExample

Downside of this solution is

- It is bit of an hacky workaround
- The title next to back-button is the title of the TabbedPage, not the current tab
- The animation to the next page is not as fluent as default

Comment: I wanted to hide Tabbar from TabbedPage. not Navigationbar.

Comment: I understand, and this code is for hiding the tabbar, not for hiding the navbar. If you don't set `HasNavigationBar="False"`, the page has 2 navbars...